# DataBind with single quoted string is not calling javaScript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datalist

**Scenario:-**
I've a Data List, loaded with with few images. Each image has its own distinct sting property ("Description") which is loaded from a database query. Now when there is a mouse-hover on any image, it calls a already defined OnClinetClick JS function. Thats JS function's parameter binds the "Description" of currently mouse hovered image. (pls refer the code)

**Problem:-** Whenever the "Description" has a single quote in it (ex. *World's Best*), "demoJS" is not called.But if the same "Description" has normal string in it (ex. *World Best*), "DemoJS" is called succesfully.

Please let me know if any one can guide on this.

```
 <asp:DataList ID="ItemSelectionDataList" CssClass="itemSelectionDataList" runat="server"
                 DataSourceID="DemoDataSource">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <a href="DemoPage.aspx?1>"
             class="itemSelectionItemLink" 
             onmouseover="demoJS('<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Description")%'                                   
         </a>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: it's bad practice, sending HTML values to the javascript function. instead of this, you can send it's description id and get the description via an AJAX call.

Comment: Ravi - Many many other dependencies are atatched with my project concerned with my question. Those code I didn't mention for the sake of simplicity of the question. Otherwise I could have used what u've suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just replace that `'` with `\'` like this ??

```
DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Description").ToString().Replace("'", "\\'")
```

Comment: `&#x2018;` user can still enter the values like this. this is not the safe way to do.  i feel pass the description id and get the content from server via ajax